# How to add options that i read from sql using C# web service into select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a streets table in my sql database, what i'm trying to do is to push the name of each street into a select element in html page, so my code is :

```
[WebMethod]
public string FillStreetsIntoSelect()
{
    string streetsNames = "";
    command.Connection.Close();
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    command.CommandText = "select Street_Name from Streets";
    command.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        streetsNames += reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + ",";
    }
    command.Connection.Close();
    return json.Serialize(streetsNames);
}
```

and this is what this function returns:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"asd,fgh,qwe,ert,"</string>
```

so this data i need to insert it into empty select element that i have in my html page by a javascript/jQuery function

```
function fillStreetLocationSelect() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: web + "/FillStreetLocationSelect",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(hazard),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            /*   */
        }
    });
}
```

now, how to slipt the string that the function returns, and how to insert it into the select element

Answer (score 0):

Find below example , may be this is very helpful to you.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "WebService/WebService.asmx/GetAllCompany",
        data: "",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                var userlist = result;
                var t = JSON.parse(userlist.d);

                var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlCompany');
                $('#ddlCompany').html('');
                for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                    ddl.options[i] = new Option(t[i].Name, t[i].Link);
                }

            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i dont believe it is going to help me

Comment: just try it , and let me know if you fetch any problem